# why android application could not be installed on HTC Tattoo?

Tags: android

Hi I am newly started work on android. But when I tried to install my application on Android Tattoo it shows error

> application could not be installed on phone.

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

HTC Tattoo comes with Android 1.6 by default. So, I think that you are trying to install an app with a newer Android version. Also, make sure to enable the "Install from unknown sources" option in the Settings.

Comment: "Install from unknown sources" is already enable but still it shows error.

Comment: And what about the android version?