# My application is execute on android emulator but it throws exception when it install on HTC Tattoo

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why android application could not be installed on HTC Tattoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163733/why-android-application-could-not-be-installed-on-htc-tattoo)

Hi, 
I m new in android, I have above problem so please help me.

Comment: ...provide the source code for your application and the LogCat error output or no one can help you... Plus you already asked this once?! Jesus...

Answer (score 0):

It's must be a problem with OS version (Even if your description is very very small...)